# Does Ubuntu 18.04 support drag and drop files to applications?

Tags: drag-and-drop

I need to open an .exe file by dragging and droping it onto anther .exe file but it just doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work? I already tried other file managers and also i tried an alternative windows file manager(explorer++) but it still doesnt work. Maybe there is a way to operate this action with terminal but i dont know. If you know a solution please tell it. Thanks.

Here is the screenshot of what i try to do:

[here is the screenshot of what i try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAKCe.png)

Comment: if it does it won't work with "exe". Those are windows related files and have no corresponding action. You can drop a ".deb" file into the "software" desktop app for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily work, it depends on the file browser primarily. For your specific problem you can probably achieve the expected result by using the terminal. When yoǘ're running your .exe I want to assume you're using Wine, in which case you should be able to run wine with your file as an argument.

From this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1058985/launch-program-with-wine-using-exe-arguments

```
exec wine "/path/to/your/exe.exe" "/path/to/file/you/want/to/drop"
```